# Debugging in IntelliJ for a Node.js Bot Builder project

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, botframework

I have a simple Node.js service using Bot Builder SDK, working with the Bot Emulator, running on localhost:3978. When I try to use IntelliJ 2016.3.3. Node.js remote debug on 5858 after starting my server `node --debug-brk app.js`, it's unable to connect to it. However, I am able to `attach to process` and debug on MSFT VSCode just fine.

My Node version is v7.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

works for me using same Node.js/IDE version:

[image]

BTW, why do you use remote debugging to debug your bot? As it's running locally, you can just use Node.js run configuration to debug it

Comment: I tried directly running Node.js Bot Builder using run config from IntelliJ locally but couldn't get the emulator to connect to Node.js service. Did you configure additional environmental variables in your run config? I was trying ```NODE_ENV=development;request=launch;port=5858```

Comment: no, I didn't use any additional variables; and emulator does connect to ap.js when I run it locally, either from WebStorm or in terminal